# How to compare the difference between two observations - excluding the NA value

Tags: r

I want to replace extreme outlying observations with NA based on the condition of if the observation is greater than 0.3 different to the previous observation in the column, which I have got to work for the large part. But because it looks at the difference between the current observation and the observation immediately above it leaves outliers such as observation "-82.900" as it is within 0.3 of the previous observation. I want the script to only compare to the value immediately above if it is not an NA, then when NAs are present to compare the current observation with the last numeric value that wasn't NA. So the record for 2021-06-04 of -82.900 would be compared with in this example 2021-06-01.

Example below of small snippet of dataset:

```
Date <- c("2021-05-27", "2021-05-28", "2021-05-29", "2021-05-30", "2021-05-31", "2021-06-01", "2021-06-02", "2021-06-03", "2021-06-04", "2021-06-05", "2021-06-06", "2021-06-07")
Temperature <- c(9.974, 9.851, 11.13, 10.31, 10.122, 10.133, -75.43, -83.00, -82.9, 10.1, 10.233, 10.411)

df <- data.frame(Date, Temperature)
view(df)
```

The df output shows as follows:

| Date | Temperature |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-05-27 | 9.974 |
| 2021-05-28 | 9.851 |
| 2021-05-29 | 11.130 |
| 2021-05-30 | 10.310 |
| 2021-05-31 | 10.122 |
| 2021-06-01 | 10.133 |
| 2021-06-02 | -75.430 |
| 2021-06-03 | -83.000 |
| 2021-06-04 | -82.900 |
| 2021-06-05 | 10.100 |
| 2021-06-06 | 10.233 |
| 2021-06-07 | 10.411 |

I have executed the following couple lines of code, which remove most outliers but leave some remaining, hence my problem.

```
absDiffToPrevious <- c(0,abs(diff(df$Temperature)))
aboveThresh <- absDiffToPrevious > 0.3


df$Temperature[aboveThresh] <- NA

view(df)
```

The df output now shows as follows:

| Date | Temperature |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-05-27 | 9.974 |
| 2021-05-28 | 9.851 |
| 2021-05-29 | NA |
| 2021-05-30 | NA |
| 2021-05-31 | 10.122 |
| 2021-06-01 | 10.133 |
| 2021-06-02 | NA |
| 2021-06-03 | NA |
| 2021-06-04 | -82.900 |
| 2021-06-05 | NA |
| 2021-06-06 | 10.233 |
| 2021-06-07 | 10.411 |

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

There is a big flaw in your approach, as every outlier also triggers the removal of the next non-outlier. Also if this is representive for your actual data I would consider 2 steps. First delete the errors, for example if your data should always have temperatures above zero that is safe to do so.

After that clean up I would calculate the mean and standard deviation and then consider those deviating 2 * sd (or 3 * sd) as an outlier. Note that with your sample data 1/4th is a huge outlier needs the prior cleaning as sd would be very high and none would be considered an outlier.

```
v <- c(9.974, 9.851, 11.13, 10.31, 10.122, 10.133, -75.43, -83.00, -82.9, 10.1, 10.233, 10.411)


v[v < 0] <- NA

sd <- sd(v, na.rm = T)
mean <- mean(v, na.rm = T)

n_sigmas <- 2 # usually 3 is used, 2 is used to illustrate one outlier in the "fixed" data

lower <- mean - n_sigmas * sd
upper <- mean + n_sigmas * sd

v[v < lower | v > upper] <- NA

v

# [1]  9.974  9.851     NA 10.310 10.122 10.133     NA     NA     NA 10.100 10.233 10.411
```